# Could we call super.someMethod() in derived class from an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Could we call `super.someMethod()` in derived class from an abstract class?

for in stance:

```
abstarct class TestBase{
   void nonabstractMethod(){
   ....
  }
}
```

Then derived class:

```
class Child extend TestBase{
   void callFunction(){

   }
   void nonabstractMethos(){
   super.nonabstractMethos();
  }
}
```

I assume this can be done. But if we have an abstract method then it cannot be called because of no implementation, am i correct?

Comment: try it, and you will see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. If you are extending an abstract class having abstract method, you can't call super.thatMethod();
Consider the following example

```
public class  RSAService {
    protected void doRSA(){}
}

class MyService extends RSAService{
    public void myService(){
        super.doRSA(); //Works fine
    }
}
```

This will work as the doRSA() is accessible from the `MyService`. Same for `public` but not for `private`

But

```
    public abstract class  RSAService {
    protected abstract void doRSA();
}

class MyServe extends RSAService{
    public void myService(){
        super.doRSA(); //This won't work
    }

    @Override
    protected void doRSA() {
    }
}
```

Now consider this case, where you can call the super.superClassMethod() from your subclass

```
public abstract class  RSAService {
    protected void doRSA(){}
}

class MyService extends RSAService{
    public void myService(){
    }

    @Override
    protected void doRSA() {
        super.doRSA();
    }
}
```

So if you are overriding a super class method you can call the method using `super`. Consider this [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) link for more clarification

Comment: On his example the abstract method is not protected so.. it will work only if both classes are in the same package

Comment: Thank you @shikjohari for well explained example.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: yes.

You can always call a `public` or `protected` super method. Like any (instance) method in java, it will be handled polimorphicly, and a concrete implementation will be called, either of the super's class or from the derived class if it overrides it.

Comment: Thank you Mureinik for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example will work if both classes are in the same package.

If that is not the case, then you should declare the method protected or public, something like:

```
abstract class TestBase{
   protected void nonabstractMethod(){
   ....
   }
}
```

If your method is abstract, then you can't call it, for example:

```
abstract protected void abstractMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you Caelos for the answer.